# How do I create a list of objects that inherit from the same generic class with varying types?

Tags: c#, generics

I've spent a few hours on and off trying to find an answer to this, I'm probably having trouble with wording the question correctly, which doesn't help. Essentially, I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class GenericType<T>
{ ... }
```

And a bunch of classes that inherit from it:

```
public class AType: GenericType<A>
{ ... }

public class BType: GenericType<B>
{ ... }

...
```

Lastly, I have another class that wants to contain a list of things that inherit from GenericType, regardless of the value of T, i.e. Atypes, BTypes and so on.

My first attempts were to use `List<GenericType>` and `List<GenericType<Object>>` but niether's given me any joy.

Any tips on how I should be going about this? Much thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
List<GenericType>
```

Which can contain any instance of `AType`, `BType`, etc. You simply do this by making `GenericType<T>` itself a subclass of `GenericType`:

```
public class GenericType { }
public class GenericType<T> : GenericType { }
public class AType : GenericType<int> { }
public class BType : GenericType<int> { }
```

You can then stick any instance into a `List<GenericType>`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that - thanks very, _very_ much!

Answer (score 11):

> How do I create a generic List of objects that are constrained to inherit from the same generic class constructed with different type arguments?

That's not possible in the C# type system; you can only make a list of an actual type, not of a "type pattern" like "`List<U>` where U must be `Foo<T>` for some unspecified T".

To see why it is impossible, let's hypothetically suppose that it was possible. We'll annotate the "type pattern" as a question mark:

```
class Stack<T> { ... }
...
List<Stack<?>> listOfStacks = new List<Stack<?>>();
listOfStacks.Add(new Stack<int>());
listOfStacks.Add(new Stack<Giraffe>());
```

Ok, great. **Now what are you going to do with the list of stacks?**  You can't safely do *anything* with the stack that involves the type parameter of the stack:

```
listOfStacks[0].Push("hello");
```

That should fail at compile time because the stack in slot zero is a stack of ints, not strings. **How can the compiler know that?**  The compiler cannot know that. By allowing this feature, you essentially break the ability of the compiler to type-check your program.

To answer "how do I do this thing which is impossible?" it is helpful to know *why* you want to do the impossible thing. Instead of trying to do this impossible thing **tell us what you are really trying to do** and see if anyone can solve the real problem.

Comment: I agree with the gist of your answer, but it's not true that "you can't safely do _anything_ with the stack".  For instance, using such a feature you could safely access the Count property, or call the Clear method.

Comment: @Tejs gave an answer that seems to work.

To clarify, each implementation overrides a method that takes in an object of type T and returns a bool - the List is for looping over to run that method.

Answer (score 3):

If `GenericType<T>` implemented a non-generic interface `IAmNotGeneric`, then both `AType`s and `BType`s could be added to a `List<IAmNotGeneric>`.

```
public abstract class GenericType<T> : IAmNotGeneric
```

The same principle could be applied with a non-generic abstract base class.

```
public abstract class GenericType<T> : NonGenericType
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a list with an instance of each derived type?

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes
    .Where(type => type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericType<>))
    .ToList().
    .ForEach(type => list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type)));
```