# Adding different type of generic objects into generic list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Is it possible to add different type of generic objects to a list?. As below.

```
public class ValuePair<T>
{        
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public T Value { get; set;                     
}
```

and let say I have all these objects...

```
 ValuePair<string> data1 =  new ValuePair<string>();
 ValuePair<double> data2 =  new ValuePair<double>();
 ValuePair<int> data3 =  new ValuePair<int>();
```

I would like to hold these objects in a generic list.such as

```
List<ValuePair> list = new List<ValuePair>();

list.Add(data1);
list.Add(data2);
list.Add(data3);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This same question was asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066506/c-how-do-i-create-a-list-of-objects-that-inherit-from-the-same-generic-class-wi/7066913#7066913

Answer (score 13):

In general, you'd have to either use a `List<object>` or create a non-generic base class, e.g.

```
public abstract class ValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public abstract object RawValue { get; }
}

public class ValuePair<T> : ValuePair
{
    public T Value { get; set; }              
    public object RawValue { get { return Value; } }
}
```

Then you can have a `List<ValuePair>`.

Now, there is *one* exception to this: covariant/contravariant types in C# 4. For example, you can write:

```
var streamSequenceList = new List<IEnumerable<Stream>>();

IEnumerable<MemoryStream> memoryStreams = null; // For simplicity
IEnumerable<NetworkStream> networkStreams = null; // For simplicity
IEnumerable<Stream> streams = null; // For simplicity

streamSequenceList.Add(memoryStreams);
streamSequenceList.Add(networkStreams);
streamSequenceList.Add(streams);
```

This isn't applicable in your case because:

- You're using a generic class, not an interface
- You couldn't change it into a generic *covariant* interface because you've got `T` going "in" *and* "out" of the API
- You're using value types as type arguments, and those don't work with generic variable (so an `IEnumerable<int>` isn't an `IEnumerable<object>`)

Answer (score 5):

Not unless you have a non-generic base-type `ValuePair` with `ValuePair<T> : ValuePair` (it would work for an interface too), or use `List<object>`. Actually, though, this works reasonably:

```
public abstract class ValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
    protected abstract object GetValue();
    protected abstract void SetValue(object value);
}
public class ValuePair<T> : ValuePair
{
    protected override object GetValue() { return Value; }
    protected override void SetValue(object value) { Value = (T)value; }
    public new T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You could create, in your case, a base class `ValuePair` from which `ValuePair<T>` derives. Depends on your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible as far as I know.

the line:

```
List<ValuePair> list = new List<ValuePair>();
```

you wrote in your sample is not providing a concrete type for T and this is the issue, once you pass it, you can only add object of that specific type.