# How to have a list of ProblemBase<TResult>?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a list of objects that inherit from the same generic class with varying types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066506/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-objects-that-inherit-from-the-same-generic-class-with-v)

I'm using several objects where they are inherited from an abstract class. But to use the abstract class must be declara a generic datatype.

I'm having problems because I need to have a list where contains a list of ProblemBase, although each one contains a different TResult datatype.

```
public abstract class ProblemBase<TResult>
{
    TResult[] Array;
}
```

And I want to get Array property. That's the problem.

Comment: Curiose think is that you jum into the problem by trying implement Problem class :)

Comment: why do you want to have an abstract clas and not just derive from List<ProblemBase> ? And the same for nested List<TResult> list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of thing happens for me quite often.  The solution I typically go with is to have a base class for `ProblemBase<T>` that is type free:

```
public abstract class ProblemBase
{
    public abstract object Result { get; }
}

public abstract class ProblemBase<TResult> : ProblemBase
{
    public override object Result
    {
        get { return Result; }
    }

    new public TResult Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Whenever you need a collection of problems, then, you can make a collection of `ProblemBase` without the generics.

If `TResult` has its own required inheritance hierarchy, then you can do this instead:

```
public abstract class ProblemBase
{
    public abstract ResultBase Result { get; }
}

public abstract class ProblemBase<TResult> : ProblemBase
    where TResult : ResultBase
{
    public override ResultBase Result { get { return Result; } }
    new public TResult Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What I'm saying is that with this scheme you can create a `List<ProblemBase>` and have your polymorphism.

Comment: excuse for being a newbie Jacob. But, I've got an error that tells me:
The type 'Exam.ProblemBase<TResult>' already contains a definition for 'Results'  (I'm testing the first solution)

Comment: Did you remember the `new` keyword?