# How to create a list of an abstract generic class?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have a list of ProblemBase<TResult>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210632/how-to-have-a-list-of-problembasetresult)

I'm using a generic type. My problem is I need to have a ProblemBase list and get Results property, is this possible? Or what might do to solve this problem?

```
public abstract class ProblemBase<TResult> : IProblem
{
    public TResult[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your words say `list` but your code says `array`. Which is it, and do you think you could describe the problem with your current code at all?

Comment: I mean, List<ProblemBase> and from that list, get the property Results

Comment: @Oscar: Are you trying to create a `List<ProblemBase<TResult>>`?  You can do that, no problem...

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your problem (ProblemBase list? where?) but I guess your problem might be that you cannot "new"-up a ProblemBase-object. This is because the class ist abstract.

Based on your other question I guess you want a collection of some sort of this ProblemBase but with different generic parameters.

As you implemented the IProblem-Interface I sugguest you use this to make a IProblem-collection instead. If you need the Results of each than constrain the tResult to a Interface (say IResult) too and you can do even this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to create a generic interface, perhaps?

```
public interface IProblem<T>
{
    IList<T> Results { get; set; } // maybe even only a get; ?
}

public abstract class ProblemBase<T> : IProblem<T>
{
    public IList<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way without use generic interfaces is listed below, note I suggest you change the array with a more abstract object: IEnumerable (and then you laverage your code on covariance and contravariance on C# 4). the other method can be use generic interfaces like IProblem<>

```
public abstract class ProblemBase<TResult> : IProblem
{
    public IEnumerable<TResult> Results { get; set; }

    IEnumerable IProblem.Results { get { return this.Results; } set { this.Results = value;  } }
}
```

Comment: I think the terms you are looking for are "covariance" and "contravariance."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract type directly, you must define a new (non-abstract) type that derives from your abstract type.  Then instantiate that.  You could then add these items to your list/array/collection/whatever.

e.g.,

```
public class MathProblem : ProblemBase<double>
{
}

var list = new List<IProblem> // better to be a list of the common interface
{
    new MathProblem(), // now we can add to the list
};
```