# How can I store generic classes of different types (all with a generic base class) in the same collection?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, base-class

I have a similar problem to the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066506/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-objects-that-inherit-from-the-same-generic-class-with).

I have also seen the thousands of posts online that say that you can put any generic class that extends a particular base class into a collection of the type of the base class. I understand this perfectly well.

My problem differs from the linked post above and the others in one basic way - my generic classes have a base class that is also generic. Worse still, this is part of a very large MVVM application framework (built in-house) and the generic base class also has a base class and so on... each base class adds certain properties and functionality and it looks a bit like this:

> DataListEntry<T> <-- BaseSynchronisableDataType<T> <--
>   BaseAuditDataType <-- BaseDataType <-- BaseAnimatableDataType

The application collection classes use similar inheritance:

> DataList<T> <-- BaseSynchronisableCollection<T> <--
>   BaseAnimatableCollection<T> <-- BaseCollection<T> <--
>   SortableObservableCollection<T>

Even worse still, each generic declaration has constraints so that for instance, the definition of BaseSynchronisableDataType<T> looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseSynchronisableDataType<T> : BaseAuditDataType, 
    ISynchronisable<T>, ICloneable<T>, IEquatable<T> where T : class, ICloneable<T>,
    IEquatable<T>, new()
```

So each generic collection type is tied through these constraints to a generic base class. Hopefully by now, you can see the scale of my problem.

I have tried using interfaces (not shown above) to remove the link from the collections to their respective base classes, but this is also failing because of some of the generic constraints on related classes. For example, I couldn't create a collection of the type of an interface because there are neccessary generic 'class' constraints on some base classes and so I get errors saying that the type of the collection 'must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method'.

One last point to note describes exactly what I am trying to do:

I need to populate a collection with different classes that all extend the DataList<T> base class. These classes are different only in name and have exactly the same properties in them. They are declared as follows:

```
public class Writer : DataListEntry<Writer>    
public class Artist : DataListEntry<Artist>etc.
```

If you have any ideas, then please let me know... I've suffered for 2 days on this problem already and my boss is none too pleased! Many thanks in advance, Sheridan.

Comment: The solution is going to depend on what you actually need to do with the items in the collection. That is, once you have all of these items in a collection, what will you do with each item when enumerating the collection?

Comment: This is a WPF application. I get passed a Type object and need to recover each DataListEntry of that type from the collection to display in the UI. Then I need a collection object in the UI that can hold any of these DataListEntry types purely for display purposes.

Comment: When you say "each DataListEntry of that type," do you really mean of that type, or do you mean where that type is the generic argument? For example, do you get passed `DataListEntry<MyType>`, or do you get passed `MyType` and have to return `DataListEntry<MyType>`?

Comment: I get passed a .NET System.Type object. I have to return all items of the individual class that matches that type. For example, I get passed a Type object that represents the Writer class and I have to return all Writer objects from the collection... internally, the Writer class is declared as a DataListEntry&lt;Writer&gt;.

Comment: You added the new post...does the solution from that one not apply.  Create some base class that the templated class WILL inherit, and so will the `<T>` implementations, allowing you to create a list of that base type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I couldn't declare the following

```
DataList<Artist> artists = new DataList<Artist>();
```

when the `BaseDataListEntry` class was NOT generic because of a generic constraint on the generic `BaseSynchronisableCollection<T>` class that `DataList<T>` extends. It required `T` to be of the type `BaseSynchronisableDataType<T>` which the `BaseDataListEntry` class could not extend because it was not generic. I needed the `BaseDataListEntry` class to NOT be generic so that I could put all the different collections of `DataList<T>` into a collection of `DataList<BaseDataListEntry>` in the view model (one at a time dependant on the user's selection).

The solution was to create an `IBaseSynchronisableDataType<T>` interface and use that in the generic constraint instead of the concrete `BaseSynchronisableDataType<T>` class. Then, I implemented that in the `BaseDataListEntry` class, so now all the constraints are satisfied. Not sure why I didn't see it earlier.

Thanks for all you time.

Answer (score 7):

There's a key principle in play here that you need to understand- that a class `Foo<Child>` is not a subclass of `Foo<Parent>` *even when `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`*.  That means that a `List<Foo<Parent>>` cannot contain instances of `List<Foo<Child>>` any more than it can contain Strings or Int32s.

To understand why this is the case, imagine the following code (which doesnt compile, but illustrates why the above statement needs to be true):

```
var myIntList = new List<Int>();
var myObjectList = (List<Object>)myIntList;

// Uh oh, now I can add a string to a list of integers...
myObjectList.Add("Foo");
```

Your use of the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) eliminates the inheritance hierarchy between all of your classes.  Because they don't share a base class anymore, they cannot be put into a list more specific than `List<Object>`

The best approach in your case is probably to make a non-generic interface which DataListEntry implements, and make your list of that interface.  If the interface provides all of the members that you need in an instance of that type, you are all set.

For example:

```
public interface IDataListEntry { 
    bool QuacksLikeADuck { get; } 
    bool WalksLikeADuck { get; }
}

public abstract class DataListEntry<T> : IDataListEntry where ... {
    // Implement these in subclasses
    abstract bool QuacksLikeADuck { get; } 
    abstract bool WalksLikeADuck { get; } 
}
```

Then you can:

```
List<IDataListEntry> myDataListEntries = new List<IDataListEntry>();
myDataListEntries.Add(new Writer(...));
myDataListEntries.Add(new Artist(...));
IEnumerable ducks = myDataListEntries.Where(dle => dle.WalksLikeADuck && dle.QuacksLikeADuck);
```

Or (probably more appropriate to your situation), if you need to know the Type of the `T` in the particular instance of the `IDataListEntry`:

```
public interface IDataListEntry { 
    Type TheTypeOfT { get; }
}

public class DataListEntry<T> : IDataListEntry where ... {
    Type TheTypeOfT { get { return typeof(T); } }
}
```

and then do:

```
List<IDataListEntry> myDataListEntries = new List<IDataListEntry>();
myDataListEntries.Add(new Writer(...));
myDataListEntries.Add(new Artist(...));
IEnumerable artists = myDataListEntries.Where(dle => typeof(Artist).IsAssignableFrom(dle.TheTypeOfT));
```

Comment: Thanks for your full response. My base classes are generic and have constraints because they call specific methods of the required base class or interface, so unfortunately, this is neccessary. I can't use your idea of `List<IDataListEntry> ` because my custom DataList collection classe provides neccessary functionality and it requires a class constraint for the above reason. This really is a problem. I'm currently attempting to strip out as many constraints as I can and using interfaces instead of base classes where possible, but they provide required functionality so it's difficult. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would go all the way back to the basics, and use some simple linq to get the class filtered list.

Declare you list of type object `DataList<object> L` then when you get asked for a type, call `L.OfType<Type>()` which filters the list.  object is going to be the most generic thing you can use after all.  you Might be able to use the base type that the all extend, but because its abstract I dont know if you can declare a list on that type or not.

in my own code, I use generic constraints to achieve something similar.

```
public abstract class BusinessObjectBase : //some interfaces
{
    //class stuff and events
}
```

I have a bunch of objects delcared that extend my base class, and now I can do this

```
Collection<BusinessObjectBase> temp = new Collection<BusinessObjectBase>();
temp.Add(new RXEvents());
temp.Add(new RXBattery());
temp.Add(new RXBHA());
```

where each of those classes Im adding to the list are all creating by extending BusinessObjectBase.  You are attempting something very similar, but your base implementation is different.  By declaring the base type itself as templated, you are breaking the base type.  Base is note the same as Base, and the two dont implement anything in common other than object.

`Base<>` is not related to `Base<X>` or `Base<Y>`.  Now if you delcared it like this

```
public abstract class BaseSynchronisableDataType<T> : BaseAuditDataType, ISynchronisable<T>, ICloneable<T>, IEquatable<T> where T : MyCustomBaseClass, ICloneable<T>, IEquatable<T>, new()
```

You could then use `MyCustomBaseClass` as the list type, because you are guaranteed that all the objects that `<T>` represents, are its children.  This would seem to defeat the purpose of creating the BaseSynchronisableDataType though...

Comment: Thanks for your full response. My DataList class used to be declared as you showed in your example previously. I needed to change it to be generic and have constraints because it needs to call specific methods of the required base class or interface. Thanks.